# Memory request in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

When a process or program tries to access something rather anything, there will be a memory access for that. How and where does this happen. I need the C files. I need to write my implementation there to know whenever there is a memory access request made by any program.

Program --- request memory ---> LINUX MM FILE??? ---> Physical Address.

I am not looking for virtual to physical translation but to know who pings, when does that ping for memory access.

Answer (score 2):

User-space programs use `mmap` and `sbrk` system calls. You can trace these for one program with the `strace` command. I think that you could trace all of them by using one of the Linux tracing frameworks, like ftrace. I think perf can do it as well. [Some useful perf examples I found here.](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html)

Inside the kernel things are different. The kernel allocates most things in "slabs" using SLOB, SLAB or SLUB slab managers. I believe `kmalloc` does slabs. There's also `valloc` I think, for allocating virtual memory to use in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try by strace as of now.

Comment: I tried using ftrace for an pid and could see instances of mmap which shows that 'ok I am going to access memory'. But actually I am more interested in about the memory access done to load that program specifically instructions corresponding to the PC i.e. text segment of the program. So is there any file which manages all this, no specific to a program but all the request related to a program i.e. loading of the program from disk to memory and then bringing that to cache and processor and data related with that.

Comment: One more thing. While i was reading about mmap, I got to know that it creates a new mapping. So for eg. when i ran starce for hello world program, there were 2 instances of mmap. But does that indicate that memory was accessed also?

Comment: @shingaridavesh: No, a memory mapping is not real until it is used for the first time. And during the program operation the system may decide to move a mapped page into swap, making the mapping not real again.